# C# Exception printing out SQL Row that breaks

Tags: c#, sql

I have a function that inserts SQL data based on a spreadsheet. I have had the issue of certain rows triggering the exception due to being truncated, and I am trying to figure out the rows that are causing the issue. (I have to query 3 different tables so I am using a function passing in SQL/command parameters/values instead of writing the same function 3 times)

The function works to insert the SQL data, except for the few rows that throws the ex message:

> String or Binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
> terminated

My question is how do I print out the row number that causes the above message to troubleshoot the data in the excel sheet. The size of the sheet is 100+ thousand rows, so I don't want to go through it row by row.

The function I have:

```
public static void insert_data(string[] cols, string[] vals, string sql)
        {
            int exception_count = 0;
            List<string> rows = new List<string>();
            string connectionString = "Server = ; Database = ; User Id = ; Password = ";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                for(int x = 0; x<cols.Length; x++)
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(cols[x], vals[x]);
                try
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    exception_count =+ 1;
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    //rows.Add(--rows number--);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Try to catch `SqlException` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: Since the limit is on the database, can't you check the size of the field in the db, and use that to compare with the length of `vals[x]` before you add that to the parameter value? You can avoid an exception being thrown this way.

Comment: If you call that method for each row, then keep a row counter in the caller. When you call this method, either pass the row number into it OR catch the exception in caller and you already know the row number.

Answer (score 1):

Like I can see, the rows come from array, so first use a lambda expression to find the rows that have more than the length that you want, or viceverse find rows than have less or equal length, depends of you.

```
public void test2()
{
        //ensure that there is no empty rows in the array... of will thrown an exception
        string[] vals = new string[7];
        int myMaxColumnDatabaseLenght = 7;

        vals[0] = "length7";
        vals[1] = "length7";
        vals[2] = "length7";
        vals[3] = "length7";
        vals[4] = "length_8";
        vals[5] = "length__9";
        vals[6] = "length__10";

        Debug.WriteLine(vals.Count());

        vals = vals.Where(x => x.Length <= myMaxColumnDatabaseLenght).ToArray();

        Debug.WriteLine(vals.Count());
}
```

If you want make this dynamic, maybe you need query the length definition of the specific columns in SQL, if you want this part I will try to find for add information about that... .

Comment: I appreciate the effort of the answer, the SqlException was what I needed in the above comment section

Comment: will be great if you add the complete answer by yourself :), with an example code... , etc.